# test of symmetry with respect to the line $y=2x$

Tags: geometry

how can I check the symmetry of a curve to the line $y=2x$?

Using geometrical methods I have that the point $({-2\over 5},{8+\sqrt{15}\over 5})$ is the symmetric point of $(2,1)$ with respect to $y=2x$, but I don´t know if this is correct. I´ll appreciate your help.

Comment: If you mean by reflection, it is not correct, for  the slope of the line joining $P$ to its reflection should be $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by reflection, it is not correct, for  the slope of the line joining any $P$ not on the line to its reflection should be $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Here is one way to solve the problem. Let the point we are looking for be $(a,b)$.

(i) The line joining $(2,1)$ and $(a,b)$ should be perpendicular to the line $y=2x$. That is, its slope should be $-\frac{1}{2}$.

That will give you a linear equation in $a$ and $b$.

(ii) The midpoint $\left(\frac{a+2}{2},\frac{b+1}{2}\right)$ of the line segment that joins $(1,2)$ and $(a,b)$ should lie on $y=2x$.

That will give you another linear equation in $a$ and $b$.

Solve the system of two linear equations. I will leave the rest of the setting up, and the calculation, to you. Please indicate if problems arise.

Comment: thank you so much!! I was wrong

Comment: You are welcome. I take it that the calculation of $a$ and $b$ gave no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate the reflection directly? Obviously the reflection point of in respect of a vector $v$ is $2\dfrac{\langle p,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v-p$, in your case $v=(1,2)^T$ and $p=(2,1)^T$.